# Удаление последней строки из файла

Tags: c

Каким образом можно реализовать удаление последней строки из файла.
Имеются данные в файле

- Sergey_Kotomkin:154:8(777)777-77-77:
- Maks_Loxin:84:8(952)748-41-70:
- Andrey_Serov:14:8(952)747-42-70:
- Aleks_Sagin:14:8(952)509-08-07:
- Dimon_Wanow:17:8(785)124-47-45:

Последнюю строку нужно убрать
Есть код на добавление в файл

```
void Create()
{
    char vvod[256];
    printf("Введтите запись типа:\n");
    printf("First_SecondName:KabNumber:X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX:\n");
    scanf("%s", &vvod);

    FILE *file = fopen(FNAME, "ab");
    fprintf(file, "\n%s", vvod);
    fclose(file);
}

void Delite()
{

}
```

Comment: Читать блоками с конца. Найти второй от конца '\n' (это конец предпоследней строки). Вызвать [ftruncate](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate) для нужной позиции.

Answer (score 0):

На псевдокоде:

```
ЧИТАТЬ первую запись в буфер

ЦИКЛ (Цикл пока не конец файла)
    ЧИТАТЬ следующую запись
    ЕСЛИ НЕ конец файла
        ПИСАТЬ буфер
        КОПИРОВАТЬ результат чтения в буфер
        ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ цикл
    ИНАЧЕ
        ЗАВЕРШИТЬ цикл
```

Смысл простой: после каждой операции чтения пишем НЕ текущий результат чтения, а предшествующий буфер. Если достигнут конец файла, последняя запись буфера не выполняется.
Фактически происходит удаление последней записи.